# Could not resolve dependency: peer mongoose@"^5.2.1" from mongoose-unique-validator@2.0.3 with Heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, mongoose, heroku

I'm struggling to find a solution for resolving this dependency. Is anyone able to please advise? Thank you

```
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 16.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.16.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.11.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: node_nike_app@1.0.0
remote:        npm ERR! Found: mongoose@6.4.4
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
remote:        npm ERR!   mongoose@"^6.4.4" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote:        npm ERR! peer mongoose@"^5.2.1" from mongoose-unique-validator@2.0.3
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose-unique-validator
remote:        npm ERR!   mongoose-unique-validator@"2.0.3" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
remote:        npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
remote:        npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same problem and I uninstalled mongoose-unique-validator@2.0.3 version and replaced this with mongoose-unique-validator@3.1.0 version and BUILD plus deployment was a success after that.